# Installation of the OpenGL AUX library

Tags: c++, c, opengl, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am working with Ubuntu 12.04. I want to use the AUX library for OpenGL. Can anybody tell me what steps are involved in getting the AUX library for my system?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/gettingstarted.htm#0080

Comment: Like jogojapan said, go with GLUT. Working with GLAUX on Linux was never easy anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to use the AUX library for OpenGL.

No, you don't! GlAux is unmaintained and a most annoying PITA.

You want to use GLFW, SDL, SMFL, or maybe FreeGLUT.